# Cannot be accessed with an instance reference, FindGameObjectsWithTag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The error is thrown with the first foreach. I'm trying to use `FindGameObjectsWithTag` to quickly find all of my SubMenu items.
At first I used `GameObject.FindFindGameObjectsWithTag("SubMenu"))`, which seemed to work (no errors), but it didn't actually do anything in the scene. I changed it to UIButtons because that is my collection of all my menu buttons in the hopes that it would actually do something.

I can't figure out how to correct this error, even after researching other peoples questions with a similar error. I'm a beginner to c# and Unity, so if somebody could nudge me in the right direction it would be very helpful.

```
void Start () {
    buttons = new List<GameObject>();
    foreach (var btn in UIButtons.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SubMenu"))
    {
        buttons.Add(btn);
    }

    foreach (var btn in buttons)
    {
        Button btn2 = btn.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn2.enabled = false;
        btn2.image.color = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        Text text = btn2.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        text.text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: `FindFindGameObjectsWithTag()` is a static method, meaning you shouldn't be using it with your `UIButtons` variable; your previous implementation was more correct than present. Have you tried logging out the result of `GameObject.FindFindGameObjectsWithTag("SubMenu"))` to make sure it's actually returning something?

Comment: Are those buttons ever instantiated in the game? Or are you just creating them in the array and setting them up?

Comment: Ok, so GameObject does add to the list, but the reason why it doesn't do anything is it stops at `btn2.enabled = false;` because of the error "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @B.A.Ceradsky That's a pretty helpful message in this case - it means that at least one of the GameObjects you stored doesn't have the Button component attached to it. Are you sure your "SubMenu" tag is only on GameObjects that have buttons on them? (It sounds a little too generic to be the case...)

Comment: @Serlite You are exactly correct. I just came to that conclusion myself and am correcting the problem. Like I said I'm new to Unity so I guess it's easier for me to make stupid mistakes like that. Thank you!